# Best way to delete "column" from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

I have a multidimensional php array that represents a table like this

```
-------------
| A | 0 | A |
|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
|---|---|---|
| A | 0 | A |
-------------
```

so the array looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string 'A' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string 'A' (length=1)
```

Now i want to delete the second row and the second column (this is just a simplified example btw).
Deleting the row is easy:

```
array_splice($array, 1, 1);
```

[I found this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702573/remove-columns-from-the-subarrays-of-a-two-dimensional-array) but was wondering if there was a simpler way (similar to the row) of deleting the column as well? Maybe transposing the array first?

Comment: The first comment on the accepted answer to the question your posted says it all really.

Comment: That answer is 4 lines, can't get much simpler than that. It only uses the function you yourself provided combined with a foreach loop...

Comment: well, let me rephrase: is there a better performing way?

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. This question is "delete" a column. The other question is how to return x columns. These are different questions.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
function delete_row(&$array, $offset) {
    return array_splice($array, $offset, 1);
}

function delete_col(&$array, $offset) {
    return array_walk($array, function (&$v) use ($offset) {
        array_splice($v, $offset, 1);
    });
}
```

Tested on Ideone: http://ideone.com/G5zRi0

Edit (Amade):

*delete_col* function can also be slightly modified to work with arrays with missing columns:

```
function delete_col(&$array, $key) {
    return array_walk($array, function (&$v) use ($key) {
        unset($v[$key]);
    });
}
```

This can be used e.g. when you need to iterate over an array and remove some columns in each step. A function using *array_splice* instead of *unset* would not be appropriate in such scenarios (it's offset-based and not key-based).

Comment: Cool. Sadly I can't google the way to find and delete empty columns. Any premade solution?

Answer (score 6):

[The PHP manual for `array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) states (emphasis added):

> Only the **values** of the array may potentially be changed; its **structure cannot be altered**, i.e., the programmer **cannot add, unset or reorder** elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is **undefined**, and **unpredictable**.

That sounds to me as if [mpyw's and Amade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565837) might work but cannot be relied on.

A safer solution might be the following:

```
function delete_col(&$array, $key)
{
    // Check that the column ($key) to be deleted exists in all rows before attempting delete
    foreach ($array as &$row)   { if (!array_key_exists($key, $row)) { return false; } }
    foreach ($array as &$row)   { unset($row[$key]); }

    unset($row);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Columns of the array are the *values* of the walked array, so you can remove and rearrange columns safely. Those are not the structure of the subject array, so you can edit those items safely with `array_walk(array:$array,callback: function(&$item){           unset($item['key']);});`

Answer (score 4):

You can apply unset() on the column on each row:

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    unset($row['column']);
}
```

And `$array` doesn't contain the column anymore.

Comment: simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

based on what i saw here a more complete function to delete recursively (or not) one or more columns in a array:

```
function array_columns_delete(&$array, $keys,$recursive=false) {
    return array_walk($array, function (&$v) use ($keys,$recursive) {
        foreach((array)$keys as $key) {
            if (isset($v[$key])) unset($v[$key]);
            if ($recursive==true){
                foreach($v as $k=>&$s){
                    if (is_array($s)) array_columns_delete($s, $keys,$recursive);
                }                
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on the re-indexing by the array_values on a multi-dimensional array. Otherwise this should be a simple solution.

```
$array = array() // your array above    
foreach ( range(0, count($array)-1) as $i ) {
        unset($array[$i][1]);
        // optional - re-index the array
        $array[$i] = array_values($array[$i]);
    }
```