# Deleting a column from a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array:

```
var array = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I want to delete an entire column of this array (i.e. delete every third element within each array).

There are solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564650/best-way-to-delete-column-from-multidimensional-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702573/remove-columns-from-the-subarrays-of-a-two-dimensional-array), but neither of them is in javascript, so I'm having trouble relating the situations.

What's the best way to approach this problem? I don't want to use .splice() because in some cases I'll be deleting multiple columns, and the .splice() method will change the length of the array, so I end up accessing out of bounds.

Thanks!

Comment: So you'll endup with `[["a", "b"],["a", "b"],["a", "b"]]`?

Comment: Do you want to delete the e.g. third item in each... (truncating the length of the inner arrays)? or do you want to set it to null or an empty string? - It isn't clear.

Comment: there's no automatic function for this. "multi-dimensional" arrays in JS are just arrays-of-arrays. You'll have to iterate over the parent array and delete the appropriate element from each child array. "columns" are a human convenience which don't directly translate into how they actually work in the actual JS engine.

Comment: I want to truncate the length. (e.g. deleting every third element would give me: [["a", "b"],["a", "b"],["a", "b"]]

Comment: Have you tried with delete?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). It won't alter any changes to your original `array`

```js
var array = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]]

var x = array.map(function(val) {
  return val.slice(0, -1);
});

console.log(x); // [[a,b],[a,b],[a,b]]
```

Answer (score 10):

This function doesn't use splice and it removes any column you want:

```
function removeEl(array, remIdx) {
 return array.map(function(arr) {
         return arr.filter(function(el,idx){return idx !== remIdx});  
        });
};
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 9):

Iterate through the array and splice each sub array:

```
var idx = 2;
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
   array[i].splice(idx,1);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhE4J/).

**Edit**:
I see you don't want to use `splice` due to out-of-bounds problems and array length changing.
So:

1.You can check if you're out of bounds and skip the slice.
2.You can create an array of indexes you want to delete and simply create new arrays from the indexes that don't appear in that array (instead of deleting, create new arrays with the opposite condition).

Something like this:

```
var array = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "c"]
];

var idxToDelete = [0,2];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0 ; j < temp.length ; j++){
        if(idxToDelete.indexOf(j) == -1) // dont delete
        {
            array[i].push(temp[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2dmf/).

Comment: Regarding his "out of bounds" issue, you could just remove the indexes in descending order... That is, start at the *highest* index to remove and just work your way down.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `filter` to remove columns without the need to modify the original array.

```js
var array = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]]
var removeIndex = 1

const filtered = array.map(v => v.filter((_, i) => i !== 1))
// output: [["a", "c"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "c"]]
```

You can also remove multiple columns with the same approach.

```js
var array = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]]
var removeIndexes = [0, 2]

const filtered = array.map(v => v.filter((_, i) => !removeIndexes.includes(i)))
// output: [["b"], ["b"], ["b"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `map` function and `splice` function for your solution. like this

```
var array = [["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"],["a", "b", "c"]];

array = array.map(function(item){
        // the 0,2 tells the splice function to remove (skip) the last item in this array
        return item.splice(0,2);
});

console.log(array);
// [["a", "b"],["a", "b"],["a", "b",]];
```

don't use `delete` to delete items from a javascript array. the reason is that delete will toss the item but don't update the internal length variable.

example

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

delete array[3];
console.log(array);
// ["a", "b"]
console.log(array.length);
// 3

array = array.splice(0,2);
console.log(array);
// ["a", "b"]
console.log(array.length);
// 2
```

use `splice` this sets the correct length and delete the item of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`splice` is cool. It resizes the array as it removes things so you don't end up with nulls. So using splice you just have to iterate through each row and remove the right element.

```
var removeCol = function(arr2d, colIndex) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2d.length; i++) {
        var row = arr2d[i];
        row.splice(colIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eB8LD/

Answer (score -1):

**Useful code snipped that creates an independent copy of an array**

use `slice` method inside `map`. Here is an example:

```js
let arrayA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

let arrayB = arrayA.map((val) => {
      return val.slice()
})

arrayB[2] = 'Z';

console.log('--------- Array A ---------')
console.log(arrayA)

console.log('--------- Array B ---------')
console.log(arrayB)
```

**Note:** In `Angular 10`, I used different methods to get an independent copy of an array but all failed. Here are some of them:

```
arrayB.push(arrayA) // failed    
arrayB = Object.create(arrayA) // failed    
arrayB = arrayA.splice() // failed
```

All failed methods were copying references along with data.