# Google App Script Delete Table Column in a GDoc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on a script to automate the creation of a report, this script creates a google document and fills it with information from different sources, the report has a table that is copied from a Google Spreadsheet using the following code:

```
  // get the Spreadsheet by sheet id
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(OPERATIONS_FILE);
  // select the sheet
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName(OPERATION_SHEET);
  // get the values on selectd range
  var srcData = sourcesheet.getRange(OPERATION_RANGE).getValues();




  // Set the variable templates on the new Report
  var newReport = DocumentApp.openById( reportFile.getId() );

  var reportBody = newReport.getBody();
      reportBody.replaceText('{date}', dateForTitle);
      reportBody.replaceText('{workWeek}', weekNumber[1]);


  // Get the data from the Dashboard and put it on the Report
  var range = reportBody.findText("{operation}");

  var operationsTable = "";

  var ele = range.getElement();
  if (ele.getParent().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) {
    var offset = reportBody.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
    operationsTable = reportBody.insertTable(offset + 1, srcData);
  }
```

Now the table inserted into the google document 'operationsTable' contains extra columns that I need to delete (those are needed on the spreadsheet for calculation purposes) I found RemoveRow(I) function on google script documentation but couldn't found RemoveColumn(I) how can you delete certain columns of a Table once is on Google Document?

Comment: Can you please give more context, and show the code you are using? How are you copying the table from the spreadsheet? Is there a reason you cannot move that calculation column to a different location?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest deleting those elements after you `getValues()` but before you put those values into the GoogleDoc

Since `getValues()` returns a 2D array, and you want to remove a column from that 2D array, meaning one of the elements in every row. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812371/deleting-a-column-from-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascript) shows how to do that using [.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) and [.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp). Both methods take some time to get used to so practice with a simple data set first.

Comment: So you're suggestion is to delete those elements before insert table into the google doc?